# Binding to property of DataTemplate of DataType

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, mvvm, mvvm-light

How can I bind to property of view in DataTemplate? Here is my code. You can see my attempt in `MainWindow.xaml` (Grid column 2, row 0) to bind to selected item in TreeView from column 0 - row - 0, but this does not work.

If I move TreeView to `MainWindow.xaml` instead of using DataTemplate - everything works as expected.

NOTE: Repository collection (`{Binding Repositories}` in MainWindow.xaml in column 0, row 0) is collection of RepositoryVM instances and its `Items` propery contains collection of `ItemVM` instances. Also, `Children` propery of `ItemVM` contains collections of `ItemVM` insances.

Code:

MainWindow.xaml

```
    <Grid Margin="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" MinWidth="200" >
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Repositories}"
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspaceTemplate}"/>

         </Border>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" 
                      ResizeDirection="Columns" 
                      ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" 
                      Width="4"
                      Height="Auto"/>

        <Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=repoTree, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        </Border>

        <StatusBar Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=repoTree, Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
```

MainWindowResources.xaml

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ItemVM}">
    <vw:ItemView />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:RepositoryVM}">
    <vw:RepositoryView />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspaceTemplate">
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

RepositoryView.xaml

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="repoTree">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

ItemView.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="0" 
               Text="Name: " />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Text="Type:" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="0" 
             Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="1" />

</Grid>
```

Question is - how can I get my attempt of binding to `repoTree` to work and still use DataTemplate?

**Update:**

Error I get in output window is:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=repoTree'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem; DataItem=null; target element is 'ContentControl' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')
```

And the same one for statusbar, because it is the same binding.

Comment: You are right, I am using mvvm (I added tags). I am using DataContext and all (not shown here) and I can bind to it, but I do not need selected item in ViewModel and I figured that there should be solution for direct binding in this usecase. I can solve this problem easy enough, but I am looking for more elegant solution.

Comment: look at your output window and post the binding error

Comment: I added error from output window.